# How to convert a large binary number to decimal?

Tags: c++

I am facing a problem. The maximum binary number I am able to convert is 1000000000000000000. Is there any way to convert a binary number larger than this?

Comment: Please define *large*. *Arbitrary large*?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. That value us only ‭262144‬ and will easily fit into an `int`.

Comment: Most compilers have been able to support 64-bit integers for quite some time now. If you want more then you have to come up with more custom solutions, otherwise it's just a matter of just simple bitwise OR and shift.

Comment: What is 1000000000000000000? It looks suspiciously close to the largest _decimal_ number that would fit in int64_t...

Comment: You need to read the binary number as a string. Converting a digit string to an integer is simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called strtoull (string to unsigned long long integer) which should work, follow the link for an example. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul

Comment: Agree on the answer – cplusplus.com as reference is questionable, though, it is known for not always being up to date. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/] usually is considered better choice.

Comment: Thanks! Will edit link